# Navigation View is not showing up

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I am missing something really basic here.

In my content_passenger_home

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
              tools:context="com.mcruiseon.buseeta.PassengerHome"
              tools:menu="passenger_home"
              tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_passenger_home">
```

In my app_bar_passenger_home

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.mcruiseon.buseeta.PassengerHome">
```

In my activity_passenger_home

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
                                        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                                        tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_passenger_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_passenger_home"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_passenger_home_drawer"
        />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

My passenger_home.java

```
public class PassengerHome extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_passenger_home);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.passenger_home, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: in manifest did you apply any theme?

Comment: What do you mean by "Navigation Bar", exactly?

Comment: Here I corrected it. Now you can remove your downvote.

Comment: Well, I didn't downvote you, so I can't retract it, but @sush has your answer.

Comment: Quality of downvotes has reduced in SO.. They dont even explain what is wrong with the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please check my comment in your code lines

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:visibility="gone" // why your setting visibility gone here.
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_passenger_home"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_passenger_home_drawer"
    />
```

Comment: @Siddharth. Your Welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally this will be the flow

**activity_passenger_home**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">
    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_passenger_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_home"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_home_drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Now in the **app_bar_passenger_home** this will be the components including `Toolbar`

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.demo.HomeActivity">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <include layout="@layout/content_passenger_home"
        android:id="@+id/mainContent"
        />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

At last the home screen implementation in **content_passenger_home** will be

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.demo.HomeActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_home">
</RelativeLayout>
```